# cachingframework.redis - need to isolate some keys from other keys

Tags: redis, cachingframework.redis

I'm using library cachingframework.redis.
I want to use some mechanism to isolate some keys from other keys (keys belongs to different microservices).
How can I do it?
Maybe something like this - StackExchange.Redis.IDatabase.WithKeyPrefix - but I dont know how to apply it to cachingframework.redis

Answer (score 1):

I think the library could expose an optional configuration option to set a key prefix when creating the RedisContext.

For example:

```cs
private static RedisContext _context = new RedisContext(
  "localhost:6379", 
  new DatabaseOptions() { KeyPrefix = "YourPrefix:" }
);
...

_context.Cache.SetObject("key", "value");  // Will be stored at key "YourPrefix:key"
```

I've created an Issue [Here](https://github.com/thepirat000/CachingFramework.Redis/issues/84) to track this.

Comment: This was implemented in [CachingFramework.Redis](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CachingFramework.Redis) version 15.0.1, please upgrade your references and re-test.

Comment: Ohhh, did not expected so fast problem solving)) Thanks a lot for you, thepirat000. Already in testing in my environment)